# Quickblox manage session and recalling?

Tags: android, quickblox

I am working with QuickBlox library for video chat. How can i manage it session?? because when i move to the next activity from the live chat activity i just lost the session because it says "Chat can't initialized" then i have to create the session again to do the calling. So what's the lifetime of quickblox session and how can i manage that.

I am also facing problem with recalling  when stop the call or move to the next activity and try to recall i was not able to do that actually i tried different things so each time i am getting different errors. So if any one has experience with QuickBlox library need help here.

When i stop a call i call this function.

```
private void stopCall() {

        //Toggle view show the smile view again

        //ToggleSmileView();

        try
        {
            cancelCallTimer();

            if (videoChat != null) {
                videoChat.stopCall();
                videoChat = null;
            }
            if (videoChannel != null) {
                videoChannel.close();
                videoChannel = null;
            }

            sessionId = null;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and when i do the call i call this function

```
 private void call() {

    //toggle view 
    //ToggleSmileView();

    // get opponent
    //
    VideoChatApplication app = (VideoChatApplication)getApplication();
    opponent = new QBUser();
    opponent.setId((app.getCurrentUser().getId() == VideoChatApplication.FIRST_USER_ID ? VideoChatApplication.SECOND_USER_ID : VideoChatApplication.FIRST_USER_ID));

    // call
    //
    callTimer = new Timer();
    callTimer.schedule(new CancelCallTimerTask(), 30 * 1000);

    createSenderChannel();
    initVideoChat();

    if (videoChat != null) 
    {
        videoChat.call(opponent, getCallType(), 3000);
        //toggleMicrophoneMute();
    } 
    else 
    {
        logAndToast("Stop current chat before call");
    }
}
```

Comment: it would help to mention if you are working with Android SDK or using the REST API (?)

Comment: i am using android sdk

Comment: can you explain it with code, of what you have tried, the second paragraph is unclear

Comment: [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample) is a sample chat application using Quickblox. It would be helpful

Comment: BTW i am working on video chat

Answer (score 4):

For:  ***Lifetime of quickblox session and how can i manage that.***

> To authenticate your application you have to set valid a auth_key and
>   generate a signature using your application auth_secret and receive a
>   session token which you should use to send requests to QuickBlox API

And,

> Expiration time for token is 2 hours. Please, be aware about it. If
>   you will perform query with expired token - you will receive error
>   Required session does not exist.

Source: [Authentication and Authorization Session Info](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#API_Session_Info)

That part fits the Android sample code of creating the session,

```
QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
    @Override
     public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "session created, token = " + session.getToken());
     }
     @Override
     public void onError(List<String> errors) {

     }
});
```

Source: [Android developers documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android)

I have worked with the Android SDK, and feel it still needs some work, esp to reach a stage equivalent to the iOS SDK and REST API.

Though looking at your code, you should use `getToken()` before creating the new `QBUser` and related video chat calls, if the token has expired, just create a new one.
I have implemented similar code, not a video chat application, but in a general manner, write the functions in `onSuccess()` of session creation if the session needs to be recreated.

Fyi, for the multiple ones, you can try checking the error with the summary that has been given, categorized into 4; [..developers/Errors](http://quickblox.com/developers/Errors)

Comment: Great that was helpful but that's the half answer of my question

Comment: Recalling? when participant stop the call and try to call again call doesn't accepted by other participant

Comment: pls explain the second paragraph more clearly, i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819697/quickblox-callback-when-participant-get-away-or-stopped-the-call

Comment: will take a look at that, it is good that you have asked a different question but then pls remove that part from this question to avoid redundancy and/or duplicate questions, then you can accept answers acc to the solution that helps

Comment: can u plz explain how to continue session with token? i m using android sdk and the apis like http:api.quickbloz.session.json is not exposed directly hence i cannot send token with every rest api since its quickblox jar who hits this and is not directky exposed . I tried creating session with `createSessionWithExistanceToken` but i got session created and call wasnt able to receive . Please explain more in detail for this answer

Comment: hi..i'd need to check the updates in quickblox now, have not been using it from some time, if i come across it, will update it here

Comment: @user2450263 ok , but m interserted in knowing the time when you used how you managed to use token to create session on other activities.