# Quickblox callback when participant get away or stopped the call

Tags: android, quickblox

I am working on video chat application using QuickBlox. Here is the situation, when i call from device-A to device-B and if activity on device-A just get paused or application get closed stream on device-B stop (offcourse). o when i try to call again from device-A i have to restart the application on device-B then it pick the call otherwise no call accepted on device-B and `QBVideoStreamView` just show the image on which it get hanged.

So what callback should be called when participant stopped the call, Actually there is a `onStop()` CallBack method but it gets called after so long or some time never get called.

So my question is how can get a callback if participant stopped the call or participant get away? Or any better way to recycling to get ready to receive the next call?

Actually i want to get thing smoother if call get disconnected or stopped. I can easily call back without restarting.

**Edit:** Crashed on recall 
When i recall i got this some times

```
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465): startCapture failed
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:351)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:310)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at org.webrtc.videoengine.VideoCaptureAndroid.startCaptureOnCameraThread(VideoCaptureAndroid.java:145)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at org.webrtc.videoengine.VideoCaptureAndroid.access$400(VideoCaptureAndroid.java:40)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at org.webrtc.videoengine.VideoCaptureAndroid$2.run(VideoCaptureAndroid.java:132)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/WEBRTC-JC(4465):  at org.webrtc.videoengine.VideoCaptureAndroid$CameraThread.run(VideoCaptureAndroid.java:107)
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/libjingle(4465): Error(webrtcvideocapturer.cc:274): Camera 'Camera 1, Facing front, Orientation 270' failed to start
01-08 11:40:14.708: E/libjingle(4465): Error(common.cc:76): ../../talk/app/webrtc/videosource.cc(458): ASSERT FAILED: state_ != new_state @ SetState
```

Comment: i have not tried it so cannot exactly answer it, but what seems to be happening is that there is a session/event/activity/process on device-B which doesn't get destroyed, neither does it stop. check through logs what part of your code on B does not stop/get destroyed when stream is closed, for whichever reason. Otherwise, if you have been able to achieve the call and receive functionality once, there is no apparent reason why it should not happen again, this is only my opinion

Comment: also, try raising it on [QB assistance](http://assist.quickblox.com/), it may be best for them to answer if there is something other than logic-code correction

Comment: When i call again oncall get called. So i was thinking we can check for active call, if any then we can stop that current active call and accept the new call. So how can we check for active call in QuickBlox.

Comment: when the call gets cancelled ..before making your call again, you can call `QBVideoChatController.getInstance().finishVideoChat(videoChatConfig);` ..right? that ensures your call is finished, and the rest can begin like a normal call. Is it absolutely necessary in your case to check for an active call

Comment: Thanks man, i did it through the way we discuss above.

Answer (score 0):

When your call gets cancelled ..before making your call again, you can call

```
QBVideoChatController.getInstance().finishVideoChat(videoChatConfig);
```

that ensures your call is finished, and the rest can begin like a normal call. If it is not absolutely necessary in your case to check for an active call

Comment: Please check the edit, do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: hope you understand that it is a different question

Comment: i think i am not reseting properly for the new call, only finishvideochat will not be enough i think

Comment: i appreciate your help so far. i am facing this issue when i try to recall. so don't you think this will fall in the same post. So can you please help with this.